# Jmeter - Use Loop controller based on array (created from from multiple variables)

Tags: jmeter

I have API call which returns JSON like:

```
 [
  "Kwara United - Sunshine Stars",
  "Nasarawa United - Rivers United",
  "Plateau United - Enyimba",
  "Abia Warriors - Dakkada",
  "Wikki Tourist - Lobi Stars",
  "Heartland Owerri - MFM FC"
]
```

from this JSON I create array of opponents:

```
List values = new ArrayList()

for (int i = 1; i <= 6 ; i++) {
    
    vars.put("opponentA" + i, (vars.get("ID1_" + i)).split(" - ")[0]);
    vars.put("opponentB" + i, (vars.get("ID1_" + i)).split(" - ")[1]);
    values.add((vars.get('opponentA' + i) as String))
    values.add((vars.get('opponentB' + i) as String)) 
    //log.warn(vars.get("opponentA" + i));
    //log.warn(vars.get("opponentB" + i));
} 

vars.put('array', values as String);
```

Where the variable: **array** holds all the opponents.

```
[Kwara United, Sunshine Stars, Nasarawa United, Rivers United, Plateau United, Enyimba, Abia Warriors, Dakkada, Wikki Tourist, Lobi Stars, Heartland Owerri, MFM FC]
```

How can I tell Loop conroller to loop based on this variable array?
[image]

And then to pass that dynamic value to JDBC request?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. To get the size of the array use the following [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy):

   ```
   ${__groovy(vars.get('array')[1..vars.get('array').length()-2].tokenize('\,').size(),)}
   ```
2. To use current value in the loop iterations use the following __groovy() function:

   ```
   ${__groovy(vars.get('array')[1..vars.get('array').length()-2].tokenize('\,')[vars.get('__jm__Loop Controller__idx') as int],)}
   ```

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [Loop Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller)
- [The Groovy Templates Cheat Sheet for JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-groovy-templates-cheat-sheet-for-jmeter)

Comment: I confirm its working with Loop and Dammy sampler. How should I pass the value to JDBC into the loop? coz ${__groovy(vars.get('array')[1..vars.get('array').length()-2].tokenize('\,')[vars.get('__jm__Loop Controller__idx') as int],)} is NOT working with it

Comment: Your "NOT working" statement doesn't tell anything to me

Answer (score 0):

I would use [ForEach controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) using `opponentA` variable (uncheck `Add "_" before number`)

> ForEach controller loops through the values of a set of related variables. When you add samplers (or controllers) to a ForEach controller, every sample (or controller) is executed one or more times, where during every loop the variable has a new value. The input should consist of several variables, each extended with an underscore and a number. Each such variable must have a value.

> Note: the "_" separator is now optional.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but Is it possible to do with Loop controller?