# Jmeter - How to provide variable from array to JDBC request (inside the loop controller)

Tags: jmeter

Based on this thread [Jmeter - Use Loop controller based on array (created from from multiple variables)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68151492/jmeter-use-loop-controller-based-on-array-created-from-from-multiple-variable) I managed to use Loop controller based on the array.

Now I need to pass the each value from the array into JDBC, so I can perform select statement based on every single member of the array.
What I try is:

[image]

But I got error as:

[image]

When I try the same statement with Dammy sampler is working fine.

How to pass member from the array into JDBC inside the loop controller?

Answer (score 0):

[JMeter log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) explicitly states `Cannot invoke method length() on null object`

[image]

The only place where you're invoking `length()` function is `vars.get('array').length()` which means that your `${array}` variable is [`null`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707322/what-is-null-in-java) (not defined), you can double check it using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script).

If the same statement works elsewhere - the only explanation I can think of is variable scope, see [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules) user manual chapter for more details.